# Trouble passing in params to LinkedIn API using OAuth2 and curl

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I would like to make an authenticated call to the LinkedIn API to search for companies by email domain. When using curl, passing in `format=json` doesn't work. When using OAuth2 gem, passing in the `email-domain=...` doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Ruby example:

```
client_id = ...
client_secret = ...
access_token = ... # got it from following the getting started guide 

client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, {site: 'https://api.linkedin.com/'})
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, access_token)
token.get('/v1/company-search/', :params => {'format' => 'json', 'email-domain' => 'netflix.com'})
```

On the last line above passing in "netflix.com" as the email-domain is not working, but the response is in JSON.

cURL example:

```
curl https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?email-domain=capterra.com&format=json -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
```

Passing in email-domain or format works fine, but passing in both does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CURL request must be properly quoted when using `&` as in:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?email-domain=netflix.com&format=json"
```

which produces the desired result:

```
{
  "_total": 1,
  "values": [{
    "id": 165158,
    "name": "Netflix"
  }]
}
```

Note that your Ruby code calls `/v1/company-search/` instead of `v1/companies`.

Comment: Oh great thanks both work now. Feel dumb for missing that company-search.